# Connect to RDP & execute command from CLI

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp, windows

I want to connect to the rdp server and execute the command on the server via command line. Is it possible to do with one line-command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows Server 2003 this is feasible using the "Programs" tab of the "Options" in the Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection client. There you can specify a program to run after logon in lieu of Windows Explorer. If what you want to run will work on a `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /c (command and arguments here)` then you're all set. If you need more than a single command then call a script instead.

Save the Remote Desktop client settings to a file. Pass the filename on the command line after `mstsc.exe`. That's your single-command solution.

For newer versions of the Windows you'd probably have the best luck using the RemoteApp functionality in Remote Desktop Services.

Comment: there is no more `Programs` tab in win 10

Comment: I dropped on an edit.

Answer (score 3):

That you would want to connect to a server via RDP, which is by its very nature GUI-centric, so that you can run a command-line command, seems to me completely counter-intuitive.

I think what you want is a remote administration tool such as psexec, or Powershell remoting.

Comment: No, I need to do this without additional software.

Comment: Powershell is not additional software. No more additional than RDP

Answer (score 0):

Create new advance Task Scheduler with even triger:

```
"Run only when user is logged on" true => show window
"Start the task only if the computer is on APC power" false
```

Run command i.e **ClearLock.exe** for extra security
in my situation command will be trigger automatic on connect. Or CMD.exe, Compare to short-cut in startup or in Run registry this method don't have delay in execute

Create Event:

[image]